# Make Chrome Install with windows Installer?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, automation

I have almost 300 pc's that need windows and chrome and a few other programs. Is there any way I can edit the windows install iso so that it installs chrome automatically after or during the windows installation?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if it works, but you can try.

Using CCleaner Cloud, you can install software onto multiple computers at the same time.

Navigate to the My Computers screen
Using the check boxes on the left, select the computers you wish to install the software on
At the bottom of the page, under the Actionsdrop-down menu select Add Software
A pop-up box will appear - here you can select which software you would like to install. You can choose from a range of well known software titles, or you can upload an MSI installer to your Dropbox folder and install that file
Please note that CCleaner Cloud can only install software onto computers that are Online.